# Como indicar con valor 0 que no hay registros en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL en donde estoy obteniendo las Incidencias de los empleados en un reporte, esto mediante la Fecha Desde y Fecha Hasta, en ese periodo me debe de mostrar la cantidad total de Incidencias (Faltas, permisos, vacaciones) que tiene, con lo que yo tengo obtengo las incidencias de forma correctas.

```
declare @numOperador int, @FechaDesde datetime, @FechaHasta datetime
set @FechaDesde='2017-05-01 00:00:00.000'
set @FechaHasta='2017-06-30 00:00:00.000'
set @numOperador=450135

SELECT CC.NumOperador,
(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno) AS Operador, 
j.Descripcion, 
Incidencias=isnull(COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Fecha_Ini, Fecha_Fin) + 1), 0),0)
FROM trkOperadores O 
JOIN trkJornada J  ON J.cveJornada = O.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = O.NumOperador
JOIN CopCalendarioIncidencias CPI on CC.idNumOperador=CPI.idNumOperador
WHERE O.cveTipoOperador = 2 
AND (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0) 
AND ((isnull(CPI.Fecha_Ini,0)=0 and isnull(CPI.Fecha_Fin,0)=0) or (CPI.Fecha_Ini >=@FechaDesde and CPI.Fecha_Fin <=@FechaHasta))
AND (CPI.Fecha_Ini>=CC.Jornada_Ini ) 
GROUP BY CC.NumOperador,(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno), j.Descripcion,  CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, J.DiasDescanso
```

Pero como puedo hacer para indicar que si en mi tabla de CopCalendarioIncidencias no hay registro de una aun así me del el nombre del Operador con su NumOperador y las incidencias con un valor en 0.

Cuando modifico las fechas a una fecha que se que no tiene registro de incidencias la tabla me queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: Resultado en cero]

**Modificado**

He modificado al momento de obtener la incidencia he retirado isnull, dejando de la siguiente manera:

```
 declare @numOperador int, @FechaDesde datetime, @FechaHasta datetime
set @FechaDesde='2017-05-01 00:00:00.000'
set @FechaHasta='2017-06-30 00:00:00.000'
set @numOperador=450135

SELECT CC.NumOperador,
--(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno) AS Operador, 
j.Descripcion, 
Incidencias=COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Fecha_Ini, Fecha_Fin) + 1), 0)
FROM trkOperadores O 
JOIN trkJornada J  ON J.cveJornada = O.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = O.NumOperador
LEFT JOIN CopCalendarioIncidencias CPI on CC.idNumOperador=CPI.idNumOperador
where  O.cveTipoOperador = 2 
AND (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0) 
--AND ( (CPI.Fecha_Ini >=@FechaDesde and CPI.Fecha_Fin <=@FechaHasta)
--and (CPI.Fecha_Ini>=CC.Jornada_Ini ) )
GROUP BY CC.NumOperador,(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno), j.Descripcion,  CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, J.DiasDescanso
```

con esto obtengo que tiene 5 Incidencias

[image: 5 Incidencias]

Pero yo quiero mostrar solo las incidencias que son mayores o iguales a la fecha de Inicio de jornada y mayores o iguales a mi Fecha Desde entonces habilito lo que tengo comentado en la consulta:

```
AND ( (CPI.Fecha_Ini >=@FechaDesde and CPI.Fecha_Fin <=@FechaHasta)
and (CPI.Fecha_Ini>=CC.Jornada_Ini ) )
```

y no me da resultados.

[image: Resultados]

En la Imagen, esta el resultado de mi consulta, también coloque la Jornada Inicial de mi tabla Copcalendario y las fechas de las incidencias de CopCalendarioIncidencias, para ver si estoy pasando algo por alto que no me he dado cuenta se los agradecería me lo indicaran.

Comment: Usa LEFT JOIN en tabla CopCalendarioIncidencias

Comment: He colocado el Left Join pero aun así sigue sin mostrarme el registro con valor 0 en Incidencias.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que cuando realizas esta consulta obtienes registros:

```
SELECT CC.NumOperador,
(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno) AS Operador, 
j.Descripcion, 
Incidencias=COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Fecha_Ini, Fecha_Fin) + 1), 0)
FROM trkOperadores O 
JOIN trkJornada J  ON J.cveJornada = O.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = O.NumOperador
```

Solo debes realizar la siguiente junta indicando que deseas obtener si o si todos los registros que llevas actualmente, algo así:

```
SELECT CC.NumOperador,
(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno) AS Operador, 
j.Descripcion, 
Incidencias=COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Fecha_Ini, Fecha_Fin) + 1), 0)
FROM trkOperadores O 
JOIN trkJornada J  ON J.cveJornada = O.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = O.NumOperador
LEFT JOIN CopCalendarioIncidencias CPI on CC.idNumOperador=CPI.idNumOperador
```

Luego si lo anterior te esta mostrando resultados es cuando procedes a aplicar los correspondientes filtros usando `WHERE`o `HAVING`teniendo en cuenta si es un filtro durante la consulta o previo a ella.

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar `COALESCE`  y `ISNULL`

Comment: @Lamak, la verdad no me había percatado de ese detalle, solo replique exactamente el código del OP, sin embargo edite la solución y dejare esto por aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190349(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Gracias, he realizado modificaciones y en la misma pregunta agregue lo nuevo que tengo como Modificado, debo de estar omitiendo algo ya que aun no me aparece coloque las tablas con la información del empleado para ver que me esta faltando.